# Kali Linux: gnome-control-center (System Settings) not opening

Tags: linux, gnome

When I run 'gnome-control-center' in terminal, I get the following error

```
(gnome-control-center:30344): Gdk-WARNING **: The program 'gnome-control-center' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)'.
  (Details: serial 146 error_code 1 request_code 136 minor_code 19)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

What is the problem? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me: https://windowsground.com/fixed-kali-linux-settings-not-working-fails-to-load/

Open your terminal emulator and type:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade gnome-control-center
```